# Использование SSL в своём приложении

Tags: c++, сокет, сеть, ssl, tcp

Доброго времени суток. Имеется приложение , которое соединяется с базой расположенный по адресу www.???????.ru обычным tcp-сокетом,пересылает определённые данные, ждёт ответа. Возможно ли использовать ssl поверх сокета для обеспечения защиты передаваемых сообщений? Интересно именно пригоден ли ssl для таких целей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL предназначен именно для этого.

Некоторые базы (Postgres) поддерживают работу через SSL, нужно только включить и настроить.